# Is it possible to set width of "navbar-fixed-top" using Bootstrap "col-" classes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, grid-layout

I don't control width of "navbar-fixed-top" using Bootstrap "col-" classes. Suggestions I found so far recommend additions to Bootstrap CSS or use of 'container-fluid', though I haven't figured out how to control width with "col-*-*" at the latter option.

Basically, I want to get the same to the following script but with navbar fixed to the top.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <p>1. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    <p>2. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    <p>3. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    <p>4. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've used [this W3Schools page on navbar-fixed-top](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_fixed&stacked=h) to test HTML above. Do you have any working ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I come so far utilizes .container from Bootstrap CSS. Please see the script below. The only imperfection I noticed so far is a pixel-wide difference in width of navbar and content in various stages of browser resize.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- start of css overwriting container, add 'container-overwrite' to <nav class> !-->
  <style>
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container-overwrite{
        width:96.3%;
    }}

    @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container-overwrite{
        width:63.7%;
    }}

    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container-overwrite{
        width:64.7%;
    }}

    body {
          padding-top: 70px;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- end of css !-->

</head>
<body>

  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="container">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top container container-overwrite">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <p>1. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    <p>2. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    <p>3. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    <p>4. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set width of the fixed navbar in CSS and center it with auto margins.

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/QEPkvG)

Answer (score 0):

Once you add `position:fixed` (like the `navbar-fixed-top`) to any element it's removed from the normal page flow, so it won't work very well inside the Bootstrap `col-*`s.

It would be better to just set the width and keep the navbar separate from the page content..

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
     width:66.66%; /* same as width of col-md-8 */
     margin:0 auto;
}
```

Here's a working demo:
http://codeply.com/go/ogg6K1uhGU

You'll see that a media query is used so that navbar remains responsive on smaller screens.

Comment: Unfortunately, this fix does not mimic behavior of bootstrap grid during the resize of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is add ***`<div class="container-fluid">`*** in your code like this :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8">

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
         <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
          </ul>
         </div>
        </div>

        <p>1. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
        <p>2. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
        <p>3. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
        <p>4. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll. A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```